# Translate the numbers before and after `/`

Tags: text, awk

In a text with lines of similar format:

```
3.1 Broadcasting 541/541,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
3.2 Prefix Computation 590/590,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

I would like to translate the numbers before and after `/` by a certain amount. For example, I woule like to translate the numbers before `/` by `1`, and the number after `/` by `2`, and the above will become:

```
3.1 Broadcasting 542/543,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
3.2 Prefix Computation 591/592,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

I try to do that using `awk`:

```
awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\//, " " ($2+1) "/"); sub($2, ($2+1) ) }1
```

But my problem is that I can't catch the number before `/`. How shall I improve my command?

Is awk the right tool to do that? Or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) is not the best tool. It makes difficult when you have to split by different characters. You could use `split` but then it returns an array, modify the field of the array and traverse all fields to join them, but at this time you've lost the separator, and don't know which it was.

It could be considered a good option (not the best) because it's powerful enough for the task but in this case using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) with its regular expression and the evaluate flag beats it, like:

```
perl -pe 's{(\d+)/(\d+)(,)}{($1+1) . "/" . ($2+2) . $3}e' infile
```

It yields:

```
3.1 Broadcasting 542/543,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
3.2 Prefix Computation 591/592,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

---

**EDIT FOR EXPLANATION** of the [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) command:

First curly braces are the regular expression that matches the text, and the second one is the replacement string. First one matches one or more digits between a slash, and a comma. The `/e` flag lets do arithmetic in the replacement part, so thanks to grouping I increment first number by one, second one by two and use the concatenation operator (`.`) to join them and replace the previous match.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Does `s{}{}` mean substituion? What does ` . ` in the second `{}` mean? what does `e` mean? (2) Can it be done similarly in Python?

Comment: Thanks. I don't use perl, but only python. Can Python be used in an awk way but also more powerful than awk?

Comment: @Tim: In my opinion, yes and no. Yes because it's far more powerful than `awk`, and No because it's more verbose and difficult to adapt it as a quick-and-dirty one-liner solution.

Comment: I see. Is the syntax of Perl one-liner for text processing derived from awk, or sed, or something else? Is the syntax of Perl one-liner also the same as the syntax of text string parts in perl scripts?

Comment: @Tim: As fas as I know, yes, `perl` is based in `awk`, `sed` and I suppose that some others. And syntax is the same, unless you must translate switches to instructions, like `-p` that opens a file and reads its input line by line.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, awk is the right tool to use. e.g. with GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(.*)([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)(.*)/,a){ $0 = a[1] a[2]+1 "/" a[3]+2 a[4] }1' file
3.1 Broadcasting 542/543,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
3.2 Prefix Computation 591/592,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

With other awks one approach would be:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/){ split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),a,"/"); $0 = substr($0,1,RSTART-1) a[1]+1 "/" a[2]+2 substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) }1' file
3.1 Broadcasting 542/543,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
3.2 Prefix Computation 591/592,Black,notBold,notItalic,open,TopLeftZoom,0,0,0.0
```

In both cases the `match()` isolates the `digit(s)/digit(s)` part so you can then operate on that segment before recombining it with what came before and after it. The GNU awk solution just has the advantage of Capture Groups saved in the 3rd arg array so you don't need to use `split()+substr()` after the `match()`.

By making the 2 as similar as possible, I think what follows makes the gawk/non-gawk differences clear:

Gawk:

```
awk 'match($0,/(.*)([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)(.*)/,a) {
    $0 = a[1] a[2]+1 "/" a[3]+2 a[4]
}1' file
```

Non-gawk:

```
awk 'match($0,/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+/) {
    # START of what the gawk 3rd arg for match() saves you
    split(substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH),b,"/")
    a[1] = substr($0,1,RSTART-1)
    a[2] = b[1]
    a[3] = b[2]
    a[4] = substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
    # END of what the gawk 3rd arg for match() saves you
    $0 = a[1] a[2]+1 "/" a[3]+2 a[4]
}1' file
```

As you can see that 3rd arg for `match()` is just some syntactic sugar, but a LITTLE sugar is OK in moderation :-).